# SMTP email not sent in one server, but sent in another server

Tags: asp.net

I have a section of code that sends email from SMTP server.

The code is carried out webservice & smtp server value is picked up from web.config, while the code hosted on server1 works (send/receive emails), whereas the same code hosted in server2 doesn't send/receive email.

Can you tell your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really belongs on ServerFault.com, and there isn't enough information to give you a ***definitive*** answer, but I can give you my thoughts on it (as asked).

Most likely, if the SMTP server is a different server than the one your app is hosted on, then probably there is some configuration that needs to be done on the SMTP server.  Usually, the SMTP server needs to grant pass-through permissions on a per-user and/or per-server basis.  So, most likely your situation is that the SMTP server has an "Allow pass-through" list that includes the server where your code works, and does not include the server where the email is NOT sent.

At least, this is usually the problem in our network...

If the SMTP server is on the same server as your app, of course, you'd want to check to ensure that SMTP is installed on both servers with the same configuration.

If this fails, look for errors... In your app code, or in the event log.. .If my guesses are wrong, you're going to need more info to go on.

Finally, here is a good resource for a coder, not necessarily for an Admin, but it may have info that will help you.  http://systemnetmail.com/

Comment: Thanks for notifying on serverfault.com, i will look into that. There is some piece of webservice code which sends email via front end app(by consuming this webservice), i have 2 servers using the same smtp, the server1 sends email whereas server 2 fails, it will be great if you tell me how to reach the settings & check/compare server1 vs server2.

Comment: That would vary by platform (Exchange server would be different from another server, and even versions of the same product probably have different ways of checking the setting), and it's outside my area of expertise.  Definitely you should try ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 0):

first thing to check is the windows firewall and if there is an antivirus or third party firewall installed on the machine.
also check the event log for some useful information about the details of the error.